# Is this a mistake in my group theory textbook?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

In "Algebra with galois theory" by Emil Artin.

The first exercise is to construct a 'mutiplication' table and show closure.

We are given $f_1= x; f_2= (1/x); f_3= (1-x); f_4= 1/(1-x); f_5= x/(x-1); f_6= (x-1)/x$

The solution is given as :

|  | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5 | f6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f1 | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5 | f6 |
| f2 | f2 | f1 | f4 | f3 | f6 | f5 |
| f3 | f3 | f6 | f1 | f5 | f4 | f2 |
| f4 | f4 | f5 | f2 | f6 | f3 | f1 |
| f5 | f5 | f4 | f6 | f2 | f1 | f3 |
| f6 | f6 | f3 | f5 | f1 | f2 | f4 |

I have problems with the above solution. For instance, $f_1 \cdot f_1$ does not equal $f_1$, $f_2 \cdot f_2$ does not equal $f_1$, etc.

I believe perhaps by multiplication he means a differing operation, but it is not specified what.

All it says is that each $f$ is a function of one variable.

I would appreciate any input on this.

Thank you

Comment: The product is composition of functions not multiplication

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formulas on MSE.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
(f_4\circ f_4) (x) = {} & \frac 1 {1 - f_4(x)} \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 {1 - \left( \cfrac 1 {1-x} \right)} = \frac{x-1} x \\ {} \\
= {} & f_6 (x).
\end{align}
$$
And similarly you can show that $f_4\circ f_4\circ f_4 = f_1.$ And so on. $\qquad$

Comment: Could you explain this for f1 * f1? and to the gentlemen above i apologize for the typing of the table. I'll take note of MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the operation of the group is function composition, not multiplication.

Comment: I would assume that Artin actually said that!