# How decide a group of algebraic functions forms a group, or how design a group of functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

Group G1:

> $f_1(x) = x$,
> $f_2(x) = x+1$,
> $f_3(x) = x+2$,
> $f_4(x) = 2x$,
> $f_5(x) = 2x+1$,
> $f_6(x) = 2x+2$

The set of transformations forms a group, let G1, with order 6 (as number of elements in group is 6), under function composition; but under $mod 3$ only.

As the function composition should be associative, for all possibilities of ordering of evaluation in three functions.

But here mod 3 is needed. I.e., $f°g (x) (\mod 3)$.

This leads hence to function composition not be of fixed order with out $mod 3$?

Say, one example is $f_4(x)$.

Here, $f_4(x)$ is not of finite order as $f_4(x)° f_4(x)= f_4
(f_4(x))= 4x$.

//Am not stating that $f_4(f_4(x))$ leads to failure of closure property for group, as just want to focus on all given functions.

Also, function $f_4(x)$ composition with itself $c$ times, causes the composition to be of infinite order.

Say, $f_4(x)°( f_4(x)° f_4(x) ) = f_4(x)°(4x) = 8x$.

So, $f_4^c(x)= 2^c(x)$.

So, the order of function $f_4(x)$ is infinite, and not just $6$.

Q 1.1. So, what is the condition on each function in a group? Is it just that : be of finite order less than or equal to group order?

Q. 1.2. Apart from that is there any criteria to be a function in a group?

Say, there is another set of functions which forms a group, let it be called G2:

> $f_1(x) = x$,
> $f_2(x) = 1/x$,
> $f_3(x) = 1-x$,
> $f_4(x) = 1/(1-x)$,
> $f_5(x) = (x-1)/x$,
> $f_6(x) = x/(x-1)$

But, cannot simply take a function from G2, and substitute in G1.

Q.2.1. So, how a group functions are split up? Or, how is it that G1 / G2 group functions are decided?

Q.2.2. How is it that group has order = no.of elements?

In G2, there are $3$ pairs of functions, each of which are inverse of each other, i.e. when multiplied together leads to $1$.

But, identity for G2 is not $1$ but $f_1(x)$, as can be seen by group table.

Say,

> $f_1(x).f_2(x) = x .1/x= 1.$
> $f_3(x).f_4(x) =  1.$
> $f_5(x).f_6(x)= 1.$

So, each of these pairs have order $2$?
Have confusion in showing order of each elements too, as operation is composition.

The below table has entries of form $f_n(x)°f_m(x)= f_n(f_m(x))$, where $n$ is row, $m$ is column.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   & x & 1/x & 1-x & 1/(1-x)& (x-1)/x & x/(x-1) \\ \hline
x & x & 1/x & 1-x & 1/(1-x) & (x-1)/x & x/(x-1)\\ \hline
1/x & 1/x& x& (x-1)/x & x/(x-1) & 1-x &  1/(1-x) \\ \hline
1-x & 1-x& 1/(1-x)& x & 1/x & x/(x-1) & (x-1)/x\\ \hline
1/(1-x) & 1/(1-x) & 1-x & (x-1)/x & x/(x-1) & x& 1/x\\ \hline
(x-1)/x & (x-1)/x & x/(x-1) & 1/x & x& 1/(1-x) & (1-x)\\ \hline
x/(x-1) & x/(x-1)& (x-1)/x & x & 1/x & 1-x & 1/(1-x)\\ \hline
\end{array}

Check:

$((x-1)/x) ° (1/(1-x)) = \frac1{(1-(x-1)/x)} = x$

$((x-1)/x) ° ((x-1)/x) = \frac{(x-1 -x)}{x-1}= \frac1{(1-x)}$

The group table for G1 is:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   & x & x+1 & x+2 & 2x & 2x+1 & 2x+2 \\ \hline
x & x & x+1& x+2& 2x & 2x+1& 2x+2\\ \hline 
x+1 & x+1& x+2& x+3& 2x+1& 2x+2 & 2x+3\\ \hline
x+2 & x+2& x+3& x+4& 2x+2& 2x+3& 2x+4\\ \hline
2x & 2x& 2x+1&  2x+2& 4x& 4x+1& 4x+2\\ \hline
2x+1 & 2x+1& 2x+2&  2x+3& 4x+2& 4x+3 & 4x+4\\ \hline
2x+2 & 2x+2& 2x+3&  2x+4& 4x+4& 4x+5 & 4x+6\\ \hline
\end{array}

Applying $f_n(f_m(x))( \mod 3) $ leads to:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   & x & x+1 & x+2 & 2x & 2x+1 & 2x+2 \\ \hline
x & x & x+1& x+2& 2x & 2x+1& 2x+2\\ \hline 
x+1 & x+1& x+2& x& 2x+1& 2x+2 & 2x\\ \hline
x+2 & x+2& x& x+1& 2x+2& 2x& 2x+1\\ \hline
2x & 2x& 2x+1&  2x+2& x& x+1& x+2\\ \hline
2x+1 & 2x+1& 2x+2&  2x& x+2& x& x+1\\ \hline
2x+2 & 2x+2& 2x&  2x+1& x+1& x+2& x\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Your group table for the second example is wrong if the operation is multiplication.  In that case $x \cdot \frac 1x=1$ and closure fails.  If the operation is multiplication and you have $x$ and $\frac 1x$ in the group, you need $1$ as well.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin implemented in subject line

Comment: @RossMillikan wanted to just show they are inverse of each other. That their product leads to three pairwise $1$, cannot be show by composition. Wanted to emphasize that three pairs of mutually inverse functions are used.

Comment: It is true that you have three pairs of inverses.  Even one pair is enough that closure fails if $1$ is not part of the group.  Adding $1$ to the list gives $7$ elements and there is only one group of order $7$.  No element is its own inverse in that group.  I think you have copied the problem wrong.  You are focusing on the wrong problem when you talk about the functions.  They are just the way of generating a table.  The real question is whether the table forms a group.

Comment: @RossMillikan please elaborate why $1$ should be a member of group G1. Why need that as identity element in G1?

Comment: No, $1$ should be a member of G2.  That was the one you use multiplication for and showed pairs of multiplicative inverses.

Comment: @RossMillikan but that group (G2) is a fairly standard problem, occuring here too multiple times. Say, at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4141396/424260. Only G1 is introduced first time here.

Comment: And that question points out that we are asking about composition as the operation, not multiplication.  In that case it is normal that $x$ is the identity.  Your examples of functions multiplying to $1$ assume that the operation is multiplication.

Comment: @RossMillikan introduced multiplication to show there are three pairwise inverse functions. Wanted to see if any sort of property needed in design of group G2. For that part, unclear still. Also, unclear how G1 was designed.

Comment: @RossMillikan reason for question is to have ability to design small suitable groups to show group concepts as quotient group, normal subgroups, by own examples; ones that are algebraic in nature; and not based on geometric properties of symmetric objects. It is difficult to learn from others' examples, particularly if there are long tables

Comment: I think it is a mistake to try to design groups to show those concepts.  The usual point of questions like this is to make sure the students understand and can apply the group axioms.  Once you have that, any example is as good as any other.  If you disagree, it would be a better question on math education than here.  I have not taught, so cannot speak to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assertion that the first $f_3$ is of infinite order is not correct.  You need to use the defined operation, which is function composition $\bmod 3$.  When you use that $f_3$ has order $2$ as $f_3(x)=2x, (f_3)^2(x)=x$.  As you did in the second example, you can write the group table.  If you can write the table without blanks you have closure because the operation between every pair of elements results in another element.  Once you have the group table you can focus on that and forget the functions entirely.  From the table you need to and (if it is a group) can verify all the group axioms.  You need an identity element, you need every element to have an inverse, and you need associativity.

In problems like this the group will be small because verifying associativity is a lot of work from scratch.  Another approach is to find a structure that you know is a group and show an isomorphism.  Assuming your calculations are correct, the second example fails to be a group because the $1-x$ column has two $x$s in it.  Every group has its table a Latin square, where there is one of each element in each row and column.  With your edit including the table for the first example, it is not a group either, as the table is not a Latin square.  I see one place your calculations are incorrect as you reduced  $2x+6$ to $2x+1$ in the third column, sixth row.  It should reduce to $2x$.  You have many cases violating the Latin square requirement in the table for the first example.  I would check your work carefully as (this is not math but problem experience) at least one of the examples will be a group.

There is nothing special about which functions are part of a group.  The functions and operation together have to produce a group table that works.  I could use six wild functions, then define an operation on them that resulted in a proper group table and it would be a group.  If you want to use a simple operation like function composition or multiplication you need to choose the functions carefully to make a group.

Comment: Please elaborate : "I could use six wild functions, then define an operation on them that resulted in a proper group table and it would be a group."

Comment: I could use $x^3$ and $e^x$, then define the group operation $\oplus$ so that $x^3 \oplus e^x=x+1$  If I define $\oplus$ correctly, I can use any set of functions and make a group.  It may not look like any operation you have ever seen, but that is OK.  All we care about is the resulting table.

Comment: Think all table entries for G1 have been removed.